# Validation controls for Windows forms?

Tags: .net, winforms, .net-2.0

Are the validation controls available in Visual Studio 2005 for Windows Forms like they are for Web Forms? I don't see them.

Answer (score 4):

this can be implemented with the ErrorProvider class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.aspx

Hope this helps!

Adam